# unable to find manifest file brightscript roku visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, brightscript

I am using visual studio code for brightscript project. My configuration file is like

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "brightscript",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "BrightScript Debug: Launch",
        "host": "ip",
        "password": "password",
        "rootDir": "/roku/manifest.brs",
        "consoleOutput": "normal"
    }
]
```

}

when i try to run (build the project) it's give me error

> unable to fine manifest file

I am running fine in eclipse but i want to configure on visual studio code as well.

and any plugin for visual studio code for code intellisense and functions reach on ctrl+click ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the requirements for a Roku project to successfully deploy onto a Roku Device is the existence of a manifest file in the zip project file, along with a possible components, source, and images folder. While the Eclipse has a plugin for Brightscript deployment and development, you will need to navigate into your project folder and zip the items (don't zip the project folder), before sideloading. If your project does not have a manifest file, you should include a manifest file. There is an example manifest file from the Roku SDK: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Roku+Channel+Manifest

From your code, it looks like the manifest file has been set as "manifest.brs", but manifest should not be a brightscript file. Please refer to the above link for manifest guidelines, and your program should work.

With regards to IDE's/Text Editors, only Atom and Eclipse are known to have automatic project deployment (with the installation of an additional plugin), while Eclipse has a built-in brightscript debugger. Otherwise, you need to side-load the channel using your Roku IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

If your BrightScript project is located in a subdirectory of the workspace, you will need to update the launch configuration property called 'rootDir' to point to the root folder containing the manifest file.

For example, if you have this structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4IZM.png)

then you would need change rootDir in your launch config to look like this:

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            ...
            "rootDir": "Roku App/${workspaceRoot}",
            ...
        }
    ]
}

Comment: "rootDir" point to the project directory root and not the manifest file ( the manifest file should be located on the root of the project by convention )

Answer (score 0):

I think you are compressing your app file in a wrong way.
Please go inside the folder of your app and select All files or folders, click right mouse click and compress all.
You are done...